# Add whitespace after block elements when using Jsoup Element.text()

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

The following:

```
Jsoup.parse("<h1>Heading</h1>Bodytext").text()
```

gives "HeadingBodytext" - i.e. with no whitespace added at the end of a block level element. Is there a workaround to add this whitespace in myself? Ideally it would happen for every block level element.

Answer (score 0):

Little dirty, but cant help:

```
String t = Jsoup.parse("<h1>Heading</h1>Bodytext").select("h1").first().ownText();
```

This will return own text of `h1` tag, so you can add whitespace and the rest of string.